# Rails AJAX ERB View Question link_to_remote

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

Rals 3.0

My question is using link_to_remote to make an ajax call.

2.3.8 Ajax call

```
<%= link_to_remote image_tag("../images/services_button.jpg", :mouseover => 
    "../images/services_button_over.jpg"), :url =>{:controller => :dashboard, :action => :service} %>
```

Current View -

```
<% link_to_remote view_path do %>
            About Us<span>Who we are</span>
<% end %>
```

How do I go about turning my current view code into an ajax call ? 
I've tried something like this ...

```
<% link_to_remote "hello", :url=>{:controller=>:sae,:action=>:bam} do %>
            About Us<span>Who we are</span>
      <% end %>
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Trying to do basic...basic.. UJS.

Very simple AJAX call to make a div go up. Though it's not working. Trying to transition from 2.3.8 to 3.0. Any help is greatly appreciated. I've googled, though I'm not able to make any sense of the jargon. :( Thanks in advance

View:

```
<div class="test">
  Whompa
</div>
<%= link_to 'Blind-Up', :controller=>:home,:actions=>:test, :remote =>true %>
```

Controller:

```
  def test
    render :update do |page|
      page[:test].visual_effect :blind_up
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Rails 3 syntax is now `<%= link_to "hello", :remote => true %>`. There's quite a few blog posts/tutorials online about making ajax calls with the new syntax - I'd recommend http://code.alexreisner.com/articles/link-to-remote-with-ujs.html, http://blog.solnic.eu/2009/09/08/unobtrusive-javascript-helpers-in-rails-3 and http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2010/06/unobtrusive-javascript-in-rails-3/ as a good starting point. Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi there Sonia, thank you for your response. I am trying to do just a very basic ajax call in rails 3.0, though I'm still unable to get it right.